# ObjectID automatically set to "0...0" in go with official mongoDB driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to save user entries in a MongoDB database with Go. Users should get an ID automatically. I'm using the offical MongoDB Go driver.

My sources were especially https://vkt.sh/go-mongodb-driver-cookbook/ and https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial.

Struct looks like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Fname string `json:"fname" bson:"fname"`
    Lname string `json:"lname" bson:"lname"`
    Mail string `json:"mail" bson:"mail"`
    Password string `json:"password" bson:"password"`
    Street string `json:"street" bson:"street"`
    Zip string `json:"zip" bson:"zip"`
    City string `json:"city" bson:"city"`
    Country string `json:"country" bson:"country"`
}
```

Setting up the database (connection works) and signing up users (based on an HTTP-Request `r` with a user in it's body):

```golang
ctx := context.Background()
uriDB := "someURI"
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(uriDB)
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
collection := client.Database("guDB").Collection("users")

...

var user User
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
result, err := collection.InsertOne(ctx, user)
...
```

When I enter the first user, it is added to the collection, but the ID looks like this:
`_id:ObjectID(000000000000000000000000)`

If I now want to enter another user, I get the following error:

```
multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{E11000 duplicate key error collection: guDB.users index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('000000000000000000000000') }}]}, {<nil>}]
```

So it seems like again ObjectID `000000000000000000000000` is assigned.

I expected the ID to be automatically set to a unique value for each entry.

Do I have to manually set the ID or how can I assign unique IDs to users?

Comment: Does `err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)` "refill"  (i.e. populate without creating new object) the target.  Looks that way.  In which case, the first time through, the driver assigns ID and all is well.  But second and subsequent times, ID is already filled in so you get the dupe error.   You have to manually take ID out of the object post-insertion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Per the documentation you linked, you must set the object ID yourself when using structs](https://vkt.sh/go-mongodb-driver-cookbook/#struct-tags):

```
_, err := col.InsertOne(ctx, &Post{
    ID:        primitive.NewObjectID(),    // <-- this line right here
    Title:     "post",
    Tags:      []string{"mongodb"},
    Body:      `blog post`,
    CreatedAt: time.Now(),
})
```

The examples before that using `bson.M` don't need to specify an ID because they don't send the `_id` field at all; with a struct, the field is being sent with its zero value (as you've seen).

Answer (score 4):

If you set a document _id, mongodb will use that _id for the document during insertion and will not generate. You have to either omit it, or set it manually with primitive.NewObjectID().